# Retrieve one month of data based on minutes granurality in MongoDB

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongodb-query

```
def getPacketLength(self,groupid,lasttime,tapid):

    pkt_collection = db['tap_pkts']
    reqtime= [1417177485,1417177500,........,1414585185] 
    total_sum=0

    resultset=[{"$match":{"groupid":int(groupid),
               "$and":[{"first_time":{"$lte":reqtime}},{"time": {"$gte":reqtime}}],
               "tapid":int(tapid)}},
            {'$group':{'_id':'','packetlength':{'$sum':'$pkt_length'}}}]

    sum_resultset=pkt_collection.aggregate(pipeline=resultset)

   return
```

Objective:

I need to retrieve one month data for each 5 minutes time interval.

I have a timeArray say, with 2000 time intervals.

```
timeArray=[1417177485,1417177500,........,1414585185]
```

from this timeArray for each time I must iterate and compare in DB collection that this time in timeArray must be greater than equal or less than equal to 'first_time' and 'time' fields in DB.If this condition is statisfied sum the 'pkt_length' field of collections and store in an array. Repeat this for all the time in an timeArray.

```
output:
sumOfPktLengths=[4,9,..........6]
```

Facing problem: (Performance Issue)

Now I am writing this mongo query inside a function and for each value(time) in an timeArray I am calling this function from server which will execute the query for a single value(time) and return the output back to server for each value(time) in an timeArray.
Hence if my time timeArray size is 2000 server will hit DB f0r 2000 times.
so each time DB and server interaction takes place which is reducing the performance. So instead of server to Db interaction every time, I need to iterate timeArray for each value(time) in the query level itself and send back the array of values to the server.

```
output:
sumOfPktLengths=[4,9,..........6]
return sumOfPktsLength
```

DOCUMENTS: This is a communication related project

In Mondodb my collection contains the below data here i have included only one document

db.collections.find()

```
{
"_id" : {
    "hash" : "d5229340b53f0493bb391c06f479da6d0ddb7327b7413414844c5309"
},
"count" : 28719,
"latency" : [
    0
],
"first_time" : 1416810981.083066,
"cal_debug" : true,
"tuple" : {
    "sip" : "192.162.2.1",
    "dip" : "192.162.2.2",
    "groupid" : 3,
    "proto" : 1
},
"tapid" : 5,
"drop" : false,
"pkt_length" : 102,
"groupname" : "TapGroup-1",
"swap" : false,
"time" : 1417444470.313817,
"path" : [
    5
],
"filter_bits" : 56,
"groupid" : 3,
"hash" : "d5229340b53f0493bb391c06f479da6d0ddb7327b7413414844c5309",
"tapname" : "t-1"
```

}

the above is one document in an collection. this document contains "first_time" and "time" fields. "time" will always be greaterthan "first_time".

"first_time" is the start time of the packet transfer and "time" is the finish time of the packet transfer.

To draw a graph of 1 month data we are taking the currentdate-1month = reqtime

from that reqtime for every 5 min interval we will get a list of time which we can see below in reqtime as array form.

reqtime=[17464544,............,171755378] will contain time stamp with 5 minutes intervals for 1 month

from that array of 'reqtime' for each value in an array we will compare whether the time lies in between "first_time" and "time" if yes, sum the "pkt_length" for all the matching documents.Then repeat the same process for next value in reqtime and so on... till it reaches the last value in the reqtime.

This is the process I am trying to implement. Instead of storing the all the time in reqtime as array then comparing.. If you feel any other suggestion which query by itself will take for each 5 min interval for 1 month.. you can suggest me.

Comment: Sorry but I'm a bit lost on the intent here. Do you want data aggregated by 5 minute intervals for a given month or are you trying to accumulate one month of activity starting at each 5 minute interval. It sort of sounds like the former but I'm not entirely sure. If so there is a better way. It also makes things clearer if we can see a sample document structure.

Comment: @NeilLunn thanks for your interest. I am trying to accumulate one month of activity starting at each 5 minute interval.

Comment: It would help to show some documents to explain better. I'm definitely trying to wrap my head around the purpose of your two date fields otherwise. Please edit to clarify.

Comment: @NeilLunn I have included the documents in my question kindly have a look. thanks in advance.